# i build a simple method which seems thats not working

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is the method thats i built:

```
public static int opposite(int num){
   if(num >= 0 && num <= 255)
       num = Math.abs(num - 255);
          return num;}
```

and now, I'm trying to use it on the next method which is supposed
to make a negative picture of a 2 dimensional array.
thats means that if `Matrix[0][0] = int 0` it will switch it to **255**
or **1 > 254**, **2 > 253** and so on...

```
public Matrix makeNegative(){
    int num;    
    Matrix[][] negative = new Matrix[Matrix.length][Matrix[0].length];
    for(int i = 0; i < negative.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < negative[0].length;j++){
            negative[i][j] =  negative.opposite(num);}}
              return negative;}
```

So, the first question is why i can't use my method?
java bluejay suggest that:

> canot find symbol - method opposite(int)

Second question is that ,I for some reason thought maybe if my code doesn't work this way ,maybe i shall try to make a method.
so I'm also trying to make a method which will bring me the `int` inside a specific box inside the Matrix.
so i would like if someone can show me how this can be done.

Thanks ahead for anybody who can help, much apologize for my poor english and programing skills.

Edit was asked to put the whole class code here:

```
public class Matrix{
    private int[][] Matrix;
    /**
     * builder that copys an array of 2 dimensions
     * @param gets and int[][] array
     */
    public Matrix(int[][] array){
        Matrix = new int [array.length][array[0].length];
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++){ 
                Matrix[i][j] = array [i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * builder that builds an array of 2 dimensions with the sizes given
     * @param size1 = rows size2 = column
     */
    public Matrix( int size1, int size2){
        Matrix = new int [size1][size2];
    }  

public String toString(){
    String result ="";
    for(int i = 0; i < Matrix.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < Matrix[0].length;j++){
            result += Matrix[i][j];
            if(j != Matrix[0].length - 1){
                result += "\t";
            }
        }
        result += "\n";
    }
    return result;
}
public static int opposite(int num){
   if(num >= 0 && num <= 255)
       num = Math.abs(num - 255);
          return num;}   
/*          
public int getColor(Matrix array){
int color; 
color = }
*/
public Matrix makeNegative(){
int num;    
Matrix[][] negative = new Matrix[Matrix.length][Matrix[0].length];
for(int i = 0; i < negative.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < negative[0].length;j++){
        negative[i][j] =  negative.opposite(num);}}
          return negative;}
```

Comment: Is the method `opposite()` inside the Matrix class?

Comment: yes yes yes :PP

Comment: Is `opposite()` a `public` member of `Matrix`? The error you're getting clearly suggests that `opposite()` either doesn't exist or is scoped and cannot be accessed.

Comment: it is a public method as you can see, also both methods are inside Matrix class, also Matrix class doesn't have void main method if that changes anything.

Comment: Can you post the code for the Matrix class because there isn't sufficient information for us to help you at this point.

Answer (score 3):

You have declared `negative` as a two-dimensional array of type Matrix in your  `makeNegative()` method:

```
Matrix[][] negative = new Matrix[Matrix.length][Matrix[0].length];
```

and then you are trying to invoke `negative.opposite(num);` which is not valid.

`opposite` is a static method on the Matrix class not on the two-dimensional array of type Matrix. Simply remove `negative.` in your call and it'll work!

Just keep:

```
negative[i][j] = opposite(num);
```

> **Update**

This is going to cause lot of confusion:

```
public class Matrix{
    private int[][] Matrix;
```

You have declared a matrix of integers. Plus you are defining Matrix[][] inside your `makeNagative()` method. Your `Matrix` class contains a matrix of integers already. You might not need a matrix of Matrix!

I have altered your `makeNegative()` method in the best way possible. Take a look:

```
public Matrix makeNegative() {
    int num;
    int[][] negative = new int[Matrix.length][Matrix[0].length];
    for (int i = 0; i < Matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Matrix[i].length; j++) {
            num = Matrix[i][j];
            negative[i][j] = opposite(num);
        }
    }
    return new Matrix(negative);
}
```

> **Update 2**

I'm posting the entire code with an added `main` method. Looks like this one works:

```
public class Matrix {
    private int[][] Matrix;

    /**
     * builder that copys an array of 2 dimensions
     * 
     * @param gets
     *            and int[][] array
     */
    public Matrix(int[][] array) {
        Matrix = new int[array.length][array[0].length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {
                Matrix[i][j] = array[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * builder that builds an array of 2 dimensions with the sizes given
     * 
     * @param size1
     *            = rows size2 = column
     */
    public Matrix(int size1, int size2) {
        Matrix = new int[size1][size2];
    }

    public String toString() {
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < Matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Matrix[0].length; j++) {
                result += Matrix[i][j];
                if (j != Matrix[0].length - 1) {
                    result += "\t";
                }
            }
            result += "\n";
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static int opposite(int num) {
        if (num >= 0 && num <= 255)
            num = Math.abs(num - 255);
        return num;
    }

    /*
     * public int getColor(Matrix array){ int color; color = }
     */
    public Matrix makeNegative() {
        int num;
        int[][] negative = new int[Matrix.length][Matrix[0].length];
        for (int i = 0; i < Matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Matrix[i].length; j++) {
                num = Matrix[i][j];
                negative[i][j] = opposite(num);
            }
        }
        return new Matrix(negative);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Matrix m = new Matrix(new int[][]{
            {1,2,3},
            {4,5,6},
            {7,8,9}
        });
        Matrix negM = m.makeNegative();
        System.out.println("Original Matrix");
        System.out.println(m);
        System.out.println("Negative Matrix");
        System.out.println(negM);
    }

}
```

The output looks like this:

```
Original Matrix
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9

Negative Matrix
254 253 252
251 250 249
248 247 246
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i tried my method now looks like this public Matrix makeNegative(){
    int num;    
    Matrix[][] negative = new Matrix[Matrix.length][Matrix[0].length];
    for(int i = 0; i < negative.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < negative[0].length;j++){
            negative[i][j] =  opposite(num);}}
              return negative;} the error now is "incompatible typs int cannot be converted to Matrix"

Comment: I saw that too. See my update in the answer. You will need to make some changes.

Comment: I have added a modified version of your code in my answer. Take a look.

Comment: okay i saw your edit, problem is being a total noob i have stil no idea how to fix it im so sorry :-(. if that not too much to ask to give me the compelete answer and not only a small hint. im so confused right now hhh

Comment: Okay. See my answer. I've posted the complete code along with a main method for you to execute.

Comment: I know that it might be against the rules here... but i dont know yet how to send a personal message. Thanks you very much i appreciate the affort you put here for me.      This is  working !